# TypeError: getClientById is not a function when using useEffect in one component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue I can't seem to figure out, in one component I get an error when trying to run an action function from within useEffect.

As far as I can see it is set up the same as my other components that have a similar function, and if import I use one the actions that are used in another component I get the same result. This makes me think that the issue is with how I am implementing useEffect, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Error:

```html
TypeError: getClientById is not a function
(anonymous function)
/components/clients/Client.js:10
   7 | const Client = getClientById => {
   8 |   let { id } = useParams();
   9 |   useEffect(() => {
> 10 |     getClientById(id);
  11 |   }, [getClientById]);
  12 | 
  13 |   return <div>test</div>;
```

Code:

```html
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getClientById } from "../../actions/client";

const Client = getClientById => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    getClientById(id);
  }, [getClientById,id]);

  return <div>test</div>;
};

Client.propTypes = {
  getClientById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  client: state.client,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getClientById })(Client);
```

Code for getClientById

```html
import { GET_CLIENT, POST_ERROR, ADD_CLIENT } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

// Get profile by ID
export const getClientById = clientId => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/client/${clientId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_CLIENT,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to a functional component is the `props` object. You probably mean:

```
const Client = props => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getClientById(id);
  }, [props.getClientById,id]);

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Or you can destructure the `props` object and get access to it directly:

```
const Client = ({ getClientById }) => {
```

Comment: If you do choose to destructure, you will have to rename it, since `getClientById` is already being imported.